# inventory management with excel

Tags: excel-formula

My previous post seemed to have been unclear so I am posting this again and will try to explain the problem more clearly using screenshots.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/4x8wktbdo7jc21m/excel-screenshot.jpg?dl=0

Now, let me explain the screenshots.
Let's take just one of the raw materials in the table, say Rosin (Column B).
Whenever we buy more rosin, I mention the quanity bought and the date(Column A)
and I have the total quantity of rosin bought at the bottom using the formula "=sum(b80:b91)".
You will also notice that the number of rows at present is 11 i.e. 80 to 91.
But we will still be buying more rosin, even when I have entered the data in these rows. i.e. when I enter the dates and the quantity bought.

The problem is that I'll have to keep inserting more rows in there after every few days.
And if I keep doing that then the column for Rosin(as well as for the other raw materials) will become so long that I'll be scrolling forever.

So, is there a way that I  could just enter the amount of rosin bought and the date without having to insert more rows.

Here's a link to the excel sheet that I created - https://www.dropbox.com/s/iod5y7jae6grmyz/brc%20goods%20received%20STOCK11.xlsx?dl=0

If you think MS Excel is not the right tool for this, then please recommend the correct tool for this. 
I was learning some python and know some programming basics - just for your information.

P.S. Hope I have been able to explain the problem clearly this time.
I admit that the excel sheet looks very confusing and haphazardly done, but I wanted to start doing the calculations and improve the looks of the sheet later on.

Comment: your explanations lack clarity and precision: give references to the **sheets/rows/columns/cells** you are talking about, use screenshot to help explain it clearly. Your tables are not very efficiently ordered, in total chaos. Your English is not very clear. Read through again and try to put down what goes in your mind, so that the community would quickly understand what you are talking about rather than spending time to decipher your problem. **state it very clearly**

Comment: I have attempted to explain the problem more clearly and used screenshots this time. Please let me know if you need any more clarifications.

Comment: there is again problem: your screenshot lacks the columns/rows references, how can we know if it is column B and not C ??? sorry to say it again, your excel sheets are total mess, you can't work like this in excel environment, this leads to sheer MISmanagement of inventory. Please give it another shot.

Comment: Oh! well.
here's another shot.
Have updated the screenshot to include the row references and have used paint to add the column references.
Didnt want to take a screenshot of the whole page as it would become confusing again

Comment: so to answer your question, i need to make several things clear:<br> why do you put your tables under one another? any logical reason? <br>what is the maximum of days(dates) that you need to put in your first column? is it month by month? <br> why do you repeat your *total chemicals used* twice in your workbook? once in sheet1 and second time in sheet 3?

Comment: Reason to put the tables on under another - I just didnt want to make the thing very wide. That was the only reason to do that. I guess I could just have all the tables for all the materials in a single line and it wouldnt cause any problem at all.

As to why I used total chemicals used twice?
it was just so I could take a look at each of the sheets
and tell at a glance, the total chemicals used.

Comment: you didn't answer my question about months/days? read it again and waiting for answer.

Comment: The intention is to have it done month by month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically, you need to use pivot tables to organize and sum your data. 
here is [an example sheet done for you](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5shne5bb9zifi12/pivot_tables_incoming_chemicals.xlsx?dl=0) to illustrate how it is done in your case.

 therefore, you need to put each distinct data type in different sheets. In my example, I have put all of the *incoming chemicals* into one sheet and created a *pivot table* for it in another sheet. 
 you need to repeat this for *chemicals used* in a separate sheet, and create a pivot table in the same/separaate sheet. 
 And finally, in another sheet, you can make a table of *total chemicals at present*, simply by refering to the data in your pivots tables. 

Every time you update your data sheets, come back to its pivot table and click *refresh* to get the latest and update your data across the table. 

you can look up some help across tutorial sites on how to create a pivot table, here is one from [microsoft](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/training/pivottable-i-what-s-so-great-about-pivottable-reports-RZ001013617.aspx)

Comment: Wow! this one really looks good.
but I guess I need to read up a little on pivot tables before I could use it properly.
And thanks for the link to the tutorial.
Looks good.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

the best solution here would be not to keep multiple tables which you plan to extend on the same sheet, i looked at your file and it is way too confusing and clogged up, separate all the datasets you have into separate sheets, give good descriptive names to these sheets. I noticed you use total rows below each dataset, what you can do(as long as you are in Excel 2007+), create the dataset and then format it as a table from the menu, which makes your data a lot easier to read and handle, it also gives you the option of total row, more to read up on these tables you can here: [Format an Excel table](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Format-an-Excel-table-6789619f-c889-495c-99c2-2f971c0e2370)

Comment: Thanks for the idea about excel table. I will read up on it so I can use it properly.